# What should we to with tags [graph-isomorphism] and [automorphism]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

When I saw the question “[What is the most efficient algorithm to sample graphs with trivial automorphism groups ?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/646/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-sample-graphs-with-trivial-automorphism-g)” by turkistany, it reminded me that I saw a similar question recently, but it was difficult to find which question it was.  It turned out that the “similar” question was “[Generating Graphs with Trivial Automorphisms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/generating-graphs-with-trivial-automorphisms)” by Sadeq (which was indeed related, but was not similar after all).

Part of the difficulty of finding this question was due to the fact that the former had a tag [[automorphism](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automorphism)] while the latter had [[graph-isomorphism](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-isomorphism)], which rendered tag search useless.  (Of course part of the difficulty is due to my poor searching skill.)

At this moment, there are five questions with the tag [automorphism], and all of them seem to be about the automorphisms of a graph.  Considering that graph isomorphisms and graph automorphisms are obviously very closely related, it makes some sense to merge these tags, which would have avoided the difficulty I encountered.

However, converting [automorphism] into a tag synonym of [graph-isomorphism] does not sound right for the future use.

Converting both tags into a tag synonym of a new tag [isomorphism] is another option.  However, [isomorphism] is a little vague, and it can refer to the isomorphisms between languages as in the [Berman-Hartmanis isomorphism conjecture](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2003/03/berman-hartmanis-isomorphism.html) for example.

Leaving these tags as they are is also a valid option.

What should we do about these tags?

Comment: yes, I was wondering about that too. I don't have a good solution either and was inclined to leave things as they are. We could edit the tag wiki to indicate that they are related, for what it's worth

Comment: This is something perhaps worth revisiting when there has been more use of these tags?

Comment: @Suresh: the tag wiki idea sounds good, but may have to wait until these tags have been used more.  One needs 1500 reputation to edit a tag wiki _and_ a lot of reputation/experience with the specific tag for which one wants to edit the wiki.  Do your superpowers override this?

Comment: he he. I can do ANYTHING.

Comment: @Suresh: Tag wiki will not hurt.  I agree that that is the best thing to do as far as I know.  Unfortunately I am not sure how much it helps, though.

Comment: @András: Just in case, the condition for editing tag wiki (for those without Awesome Moderator Powers (TM)) is [you have rep points ≥ 1500] and [either you are among top 20 answerers for this tag or the sum of votes to your answers for this tag is ≥ +100].  Currently, it seems that an answer with positive score is almost always enough to let you enter among the top 20 for that tag except for a few very common tags.